# Image not showing using a custom function and get_post_meta

Tags: images, metabox, post-meta

I'm trying to create a function to display either a theme option or custom images based on user input.

So basically, it's a custom meta box. The user selects either a display header image OR they can upload one they want to use.

I've created a custom function to call later on the single page template. This is what I have so far.

```
//El display image
function el_display(){
    global $post;
    $eldisplay = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_el_theme', true);
    $elcustomdisplay = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_custom_image', true);

        if(isset($eldisplay)){
            echo '<img src="' . $eldisplay . '" />';
                }elseif(isset($elcustomdisplay)){
                echo '<img src="' . $elcustomdisplay . '" />';
            }else{
                echo '<img src="' . EL_IMG . 'mobile-development.jpg' . '" />';
            }
}
```

When I call the function later (using  el_display(); ), there is no display image showing. I'm a little stuck and have been trying to fix this for hours.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

---

**UPDATE**
Ok, thanks to all for helping me out and pointing me in the right direction. I do have some code clean up to do and a possible all out change in code but I'll use this for now.

I got it to work with the following code.

```
//El display image
function el_display(){
    global $post;
    $eldisplay = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_el_theme', true);
    $elcustomdisplay = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_custom_image', true);

        if(!empty($eldisplay)){
            echo '<img src="' . $eldisplay . '" />';
                }elseif(!empty($elcustomdisplay) && isset($elcustomdisplay)){
                echo '<img src="' . $elcustomdisplay . '" />';
            }else{
                echo '<img src="' . EL_IMG . 'mobile-development.jpg' . '" />';
            }
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Check the page source to see if an `<img>` tag is sent to the browser. Then check to see if the `src` attribute is set to a valid image path.

Comment: Relying on `global $post` is a bit risky in my opinion. (I'd pass the `$post` data into the function explicitly.) Is that variable set correctly?

Comment: I second the above. Also, you will want to use [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) rather than `isset` in the conditional.

Comment: @CharlesClarkson - I just checked the source and an image tag is set however there is no source attribute or valid image path.

I checked the database and the image path is there but not displaying in the source.

Comment: @s_ha_dum - Sorry but I'm not sure I understand (sorry noob question). Do you mean to run a new WP query in the function?

Comment: No. Just define the function like `function el_display($post){...}` and supply a post object when using the function.

Comment: @JohannesPille - I got it to work with `empty` instead of `isset`.

@s_ha_dum - I will do some more research and updat the code to what you've recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE Ok, thanks to all for helping me out and pointing me in the right direction. I do have some code clean up to do and a possible all out change in code but I'll use this for now.

I got it to work with the following code.

```
//El display image
function el_display(){
    global $post;
    $eldisplay = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_el_theme', true);
    $elcustomdisplay = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_custom_image', true);

        if(!empty($eldisplay)){
            echo '<img src="' . $eldisplay . '" />';
                }elseif(!empty($elcustomdisplay) && isset($elcustomdisplay)){
                echo '<img src="' . $elcustomdisplay . '" />';
            }else{
                echo '<img src="' . EL_IMG . 'mobile-development.jpg' . '" />';
            }
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Why did you check to see if `$elcustomdisplay` was set (`isset($elcustomdisplay)`), but not do the same for `$eldisplay`. I'm not saying either way is right or wrong. I'm just curious why you did it on one, but not on the other.

Comment: I ended up changing that, thanks for the suggestion.